# How to use ionic with angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Currently I am using ionic framework with angular. Below are app.js, index.html

I am not able to access logInAsFarmer function in index.html please let me know if I am missing something.

// Ionic Starter App

```
// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
      init();
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup',
        function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

            function init() {

            }

        $scope.logInAsFarmer = function() {
            alert('Called khuda');
        }

} ]);
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">



  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter"> 
      <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <button style= "margin-top:100px;margin-left:330px;height:40px;width:135px;"class="button button-balanced" ng-click="logInAsFarmer()">
                Farmer Login
            </button>
      </div-
<!--
<button style= "margin-top:100px;margin-left:330px;height:40px;width:135px;"class="button button-balanced" ngClick="logInAsFarmer()">
                Farmer Login
            </button>
-->
    <ion-pane  ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div>

            <button style= "margin-top:10px;margin-left:330px"class="button button-balanced" ng-click="logInAsFarmer()">
                Merchant Login
            </button>
        </div>
       <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">

      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
      <script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
              <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Also your html is poorly formatted and some of it invalid, change `</div-` to `</div>` for a start. And why are you using main controller twice in your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have formatted your code a bit better and cleaned out some invalid closing tags and duplicate code.

You had 2 references to your main controller, I have now changed this to one.

Use this as a starting point:

```js
// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
      // for form inputs)
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

      // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
      // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
      // a much nicer keyboard experience.
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$ionicPopup',
  function($scope, $ionicPopup) {

    $scope.logInAsFarmer = function() {
      alert('Called khuda');
    }

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
  
  <title></title>

  <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body ng-app="starter">

  <div ng-controller="MainController">

    <ion-pane ng-controller="MainController">

      <div class="bar bar-header bar-balanced">
        <h1 class="title">hello</h1>
        <button class="button button-balanced" ng-click="logInAsFarmer()">
          Merchant Login
        </button>
      </div>

      <div class="bar bar-footer bar-balanced">
      </div>

      <ion-content>
      </ion-content>

    </ion-pane>

    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.3.1/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</body>

</html>
```